# how to search for specific barcode reading in the sparse matrix from RNAseq data

Tags: r

i have a large sparse matrix representing RNAseq results, where columns are different barcodes, and rows are different features. There is a subset of barcodes that I want to extract for further analysis. I have a table containing the specific barcode numbers that I want to extract. How can I do it?

For example, the sparse matrix is like this

> subset_SeuratObj_acti@assays$RNA[1:2,1:3]
> 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
> FemaleN_AAACCCATCAGGAACG-1 FemaleN_AAAGAACGTCGTCGGT-1 FemaleN_AAAGAACTCCCTCTAG-1
> Xkr4                      2.191203         3.280295                   1.582166
> Gm18956                   .                          .                          .

And the subset of barcodes that I want to extract is in the following table

> total[1:4,1:2]
> orig.ident nCount_RNA
> FemaleN_AAACCCATCAGGAACG-1 PeriLC_FemaleN      12585
> FemaleN_AAAGAACGTCGTCGGT-1 PeriLC_FemaleN       6254
> FemaleN_AAAGAACTCCCTCTAG-1 PeriLC_FemaleN      10348
> FemaleN_AAAGGATCATCGAGCC-1 PeriLC_FemaleN       8246

the specific barcodes I want to extract are FemaleN_AAAGAACGTCGTCGGT-1 and so on.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It would work out in this way. Hope it helpful to others.

> a<-colnames(subset_SeuratObj_acti@assays$RNA)
> b<-row.names(total)
> c=is.element(a,b)
> d<-subset_SeuratObj_acti@assays$RNA[,c]